# PHP codes inserting foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert a foreign key value in my form. but fail to do so. Before I add FK, it is successfully added to the database.

[image: My form. "Empno" is a foreign key to a "compliance table"]

[image: Is this coding correct?]

Comment: copy-paste your code snippet here instead of an image

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(0);
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mttiem");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$c = $_POST["date"];
$d = $_POST["time"];
$e = $_POST["module"];
$f = $_POST['category'];
$g = $_POST['observation'];
$h = $_POST["observer"];
$i = $_POST["empno"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO compliance (date,time,module,category,observation,observer,empno)"." VALUES ('$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?> @Nidhi like this

Comment: What is data type of `date` and `time` column in table schema?@FAR

Comment: for date is date, and for time is time

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not for clarification. PS This is a faq, next time please google a few clear statements of your title/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated **Before I add FK, it is successfully added to the database.**.

When two table are binded with `foreign key` relationship, in that case you can only insert those values in `child table` which are already present in `parent table`.

So may be the value you are trying to insert is not present in the parent table.

Comment: I try to truncate the table first and then insert the value back. Success ~ Thank you